# Shell Script for Auto IP Change

Tags: linux, shell, asterisk

I am newbie to Linux/Asterisk. I am trying to write a shell script that would look for my SIP trunk registration, if found UNREACHABLE then it would execute a command and check my local IP, if my local IP is 192.168.1.106 then it would change the IP to 192.168.1.150 and vice versa, after that issue the commands, network service restart and amportal restart.

I have written following so far, and just by the looks, it seems wrong. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash
asteriskbin=`which asterisk`
interval=10
ippath=/sbin/ifconfig
ip1=192.168.1.106
ip2=192.168.1.150
trunk="siptrunk"
run=true
while [[ "$run" == "true" ]]; do
checktrunk=`$asteriskbin -rx “sip show peer $trunk” | grep Status | grep -wc OK`
if [[ $checktrunk == 0 ]]; then
echo “TEST Trunk Down”
else
echo “SIP trunk registration OK.”
whatip=`$ippath eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'
if [[ $whatip == $ip1 ]]; then 
ifconfig eth0 $ip2
else
ifconfig eth0 $ip1
network service restart
amportal restart
fi
sleep $interval
done
exit 1
```

Comment: Please be specific about what you think is wrong.

Comment: Just gonna throw this out there -- make sure you're running whatever script that changes IP via ifconfig as root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things which spring out:

- You should be using `"` quotes.
- The `whatip=` command substitution is not ended anywhere.
- You should [use `$(cmd)` instead of `` `cmd` ``](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)
- [Use More Quotes!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)
- `$run` and `exit 1` are useless since `$run` is never set to anything other than `true`.
- `ifconfig` is [deprecated in favour of `ip`](https://serverfault.com/a/458639/11292).
- There's no point in saving `which asterisk` to a variable. Simply run `asterisk`; it will perform the exact same lookup.

[Why are you doing this in the first place?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) I don't see how continually changing your IP is useful.

Comment: My SIP trunks go UNREACHABLE every few days, sometimes after 2, sometimes 3. The only way to bring them back online is change my local IP. http://forums.asterisk.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=90610
Hence I am tryin to write a script that would detect my trunk unreachable and do the IP change and also restart Asterisk.

Comment: Then the issue is the changing IP, and this workaround is likely to be very brittle.